# SQL Server triggers and sqlalchemy interference problem. Help needed

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sqlalchemy

I need to have a kind of 'versioning' for some critical tables, and tried to implement it in a rather simple way:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Address] (
  [id] bigint IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
  [post_code] bigint NULL,
...
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Address_History] (
  [id] bigint NOT NULL,
  [id_revision] bigint NOT NULL,
  [post_code] bigint NULL,
...
  CONSTRAINT [PK_Address_History] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id], [id_revision]),
  CONSTRAINT [FK_Address_History_Address]...
  CONSTRAINT [FK_Address_History_Revision]...
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Revision] (
  [id] bigint IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
  [id_revision_operation] bigint NULL,
  [id_document_info] bigint NULL,
  [description] varchar(255) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NULL,
  [date_revision] datetime NULL,
...
)
```

and a bunch of triggers on insert/update/delete for each table, that is intended to store it's changes.

My application is based on PyQt + sqlalchemy, and when I try to insert an entity, that is stored in a versioned table, sqlalchemy fires an error:

```
The target table 'Heritage' of the DML statement cannot have 
any enabled triggers if the statement contains 
an OUTPUT clause without INTO clause. 
(334) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] 
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]
[SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")
```

What should I do? I must use sqlalchemy.
If one can give an advice to me, how can I implement versioning without triggers, it'd be cool.

Comment: As the error says, your SQL statement obviously contains an `OUTPUT` clause, right? Can you turn that into an `OUTPUT (columns) INTO (table variable)` clause?? That should (hopefully) fix the issue the error mentions...

Comment: sqlalchemy is ORM tool, and it makes sql queries for insert, update ot delete entities by itself :|

Comment: Not familiar with SQL Alchemy - is there a way to "lie" to it when configuring it, such that it believes it's talking to a SQL Server 2000 instance (rather than a later version, and assuming you don't need later features)? SQL Server 2000 didn't have the OUTPUT clause, so it presumably wouldn't generate such SQL.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Good idea, but there is no way. sqlalchemy obtains instance type from sql driver :) But it has data mapping option, that solves problem. But now, when I insert an entity into DB,  it's id isn't obtained in the save query, and I have to force sqlalchemy to reread it! I'd rather reimplement versioning and banish triggers, this issue is rather bad:/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set 'implicit_returning' to 'False' to avoid "OUTPUT" usage in query generated by SQLAlchemy (and this should resolve your issue):

```
class Company(sqla.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'dbnamere'
    __tablename__ = 'tblnamehere'
    __table_args__ = {'implicit_returning': False}  # http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mssql.html#triggers
    id = sqla.Column('ncompany_id', sqla.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
```

Comment: Before anyone implements this, please read the following answers.

Answer (score 1):

I cant seem to add a comment so adding another answer.

It's not that complicated and I would suggest it's less fragile than putting 1/2 your business logic in your domain and the other half in your database trigger.

Personally I would write my own list object with a reference to the history list for the some_list_of_other_entities and in the Remove and Add methods maintain your history records.

This way your objects are automatically up to date before even saving them into your ORM.

```
public class ListOfOtherEntities : System.Collections.IEnumerable
{
    // Add list stuff here...

    public void Remove(MyEntity obj)
    {
        this.List.Remove(obj);
        this.History.Add(new History("Added a object!");
    }

    public void Remove(MyEntity obj)
    {
        this.List.Remove(obj);
        this.History.Add(new History("Removed a object!");
    }
}
```

This way your objects are automatically up to date before even saving them into your ORM and another developer looking at the code can see what you have done quite easily.

Comment: Thanks, it's idea is rather good. I can monkey-patch sqlalchemy's instrumented list for versioned entities and get behaviour I want, thanks Python for it is dynamic language :)

Comment: I still can't get this behaviour when I commit single entity to DB, because entity doesn't know, how to deal with DB, but I think I can modify db mapper. It's interesting, beside, how can one do this using static typed languages, f.x. CLR based ones and ORM like NHibernate...

Comment: I guess you have made your entity maintain the history that needs saving to the DB: entity.some_list_of_other_entities and entity.list_of_history_for_other_entities...

Comment: Out of interest I had the same problem about 6 months ago, I had to add a check to see if the item was new before adding the history, but the rest of it works well.

Answer (score 0):

This won't answer your question directly but in my experience using Triggers leads to endless pain so avoid them at all cost. If you manage all of the data yourself then the simple answer is populate the version history tables yourself. It also means you have all of your business logic in one place which is a bonus!

Comment: I use ORM, so I'd rather avoid placing some explicit history-storing logic in my app. Just imagine that somewhere at your code: entity.some_list_of_other_entities.remove(entity_to_delete); entity.history.append(entity-to-delete) everywhere at your code. It's complicated, VERY fragile and tend you to bound entity and and its history on ORM layer, which is just BAAAAAD. So, I just accepted  this strange behaviour and keep in mind, that i must call refresh from database in some cases.

Comment: Can you give an advice, how can one properly implement versioning with Relational data <-(made by third-party ORM vendor)-> Object data  <-> Business logic approach.